# UITextView Scrolling / ContainHeight unusual behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I need to change UITextView Frame height dynamically with respect to content height of it. i.e. so when ever contain height is increased rather than allowing user to scroll i would like to change my UITextView's Frame height so users can read all data.

So here i my code snipper,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _txtView.delegate = self;
    previousheight = _txtView.contentSize.height;
    NSLog(@"%.2f",previousheight);
}
```

**Here i am getting log value -> 22.**

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSLog(@"%.2f",textView.contentSize.height);
}
```

**Here i am getting log value -> 36.**

===============================================================================

Now another way, if i disable scrolling of UITextView then i am getting perfect/expected result. Only thing is i am not able to enable scrolling afterward.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _txtView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
    previousheight = _txtView.contentSize.height;
    NSLog(@"%.2f",previousheight);
}
```

**Here i am getting log value -> 30.**

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSLog(@"%.2f",textView.contentSize.height);
    txtView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

**Here i am getting log value -> 30.**

But now there are no scrolling, although i have enable scrolling view.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this as a bug on iOS 7.0 to Apple yesterday.

I can calculate the text height correctly using 'boundingRectWithSize:...' but if scrolling is disabled the text gets cut off no matter the height.

A solution that sometimes works is:

```
textView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
textView.text = @"Lorem ipsum...";
textView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
```